# CodeIgniter: how to return data from a form validation callback

Tags: forms, codeigniter

Here is my CI form validation rule:

```
$datetime_string = $this->form_validation->set_rules('event_date', 'Select', 'callback_date_validate');
```

Here is my callback:

```
function date_validate($select_value)
{
    $year = '';
    $month = '';
    $day = '';
    $hour = '';
    $minutes = '';

    $datetime = $this->input->post('event_date');
    if (strpos($datetime, ' @ ') !== 'FALSE' && $datetime != '')
    { 
        $datetime_explode = explode(' @ ', $datetime);
        if (strpos($datetime_explode[0], '/') !== 'FALSE' && $datetime_explode != '')
        {
            $date_explode = explode('/', $datetime_explode[0]);
            $year = $date_explode[2];
            $month = $date_explode[1];
            $day = $date_explode[0];    
        }
        if (strpos($datetime_explode[1], ':') !== 'FALSE')
        {
            $time_explode = explode(':', $datetime_explode[1]);
            $hour = $time_explode[0];
            if (strpos($time_explode[1], ' ') !== 'FALSE')
            {
                $minutes_explode = explode(' ', $time_explode[1]);
                $minutes = $minutes_explode[0];
                $am_pm = $minutes_explode[1];

                if ($am_pm == 'PM' || $am_pm == 'pm')
                    $hour += 12;    
            }
        }
    }

    $datetime_string = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day . ' ' . $hour . ':' . $minutes . ':00';

    if (!preg_match('/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} 2[0-3]|[01][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/', $datetime_string))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('date_validate', 'Oops');
    }
    else // user picked something
    {
        return $datetime_string;
    }
}
```

According to the CI documentation, you can return data from a form validation callback, but by setting the rule equal to a variable, I get this error:

```
Object of class CI_Form_validation could not be converted to string
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to just return `TRUE` or `FALSE` and see if you function is being call correctly

Comment: I did and it is.  The problem seems to have to do with setting the rule equal to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
$datetime = $this->input->post('event_date');
```

The value of event_date field is captured in a parameter of your function $select_value try using your parameter instead of post data.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->form_validation->set_rules(...);` should be called inline and not assigned to a variable. You have assigned it to `$datetime_string`. Remove this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you ever solved this but I was scratching around the documentation wondering the same thing as your question.

First of all, you just want...
`$this->form_validation->set_rules('event_date', 'Select', 'callback_date_validate');`
Don't assign it to a variable.

Next, you want to run your validation rules/callbacks...

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
    // VALIDATION OK, CHECK OUR CALLBACK DATA
    var_dump($this->input->post());
}
```

Now you should see your data returned from the callback in...  `$this->input->post('event_date');`

The thing that confused me about returning data from callbacks was this thread on the official CI forums... http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/191087/ where people are suggesting that the callback doesn't change the POSTed data. They are only partially correct. It doesn't change it under `$_POST['whatever']` but it does change it in `$this->input->post('whatever')`

As this was the 3rd result in Google I hope this helps someone out.