# codeigniter form callback value

Tags: php, codeigniter, callback, validation

Im carrying out some form validation with codeigniter using a custom validation callback.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('testPost', 'test', 'callback_myTest');
```

The callback runs in a model and works as expected if the return value is TRUE or FALSE. However the docs also say you can return a string of your choice.

For example if I have a date which is validated, but then in the same function the format of the date is changed how would I return and retrieve this new formatted value back in my controller?

Thanks for reading and appreiate the help.

Comment: a vote down without a comment? A bit harsh. I did look to see if the question exists. the closest I found was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486274/codeigniter-how-to-return-data-from-a-form-validation-callback which didnt answer my question

Comment: I have no idea why you got votedown but here's +1 from me. This question is a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I got what you were asking, but here's an attempt.

You could define a function within the constructor that serves as the callback, and from within that function use your model. Something like this:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Controllername extends CI_Controller {

   private $processedValue;

   public function index()
   {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('testpost','test','callback');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
         //validation successful
         echo $this->processedValue; //outputs the value returned by the model
        } else {
         //validation failed
        }
   }

   private function callback($input)
   {
        $this->load->model('yourmodel');
        $return = $this->yourmodel->doStuff($input);

        //now you have the user's input in $input
        // and the returned value in $return

        //do some checks and return true/false

        $this->processedValue = $return;
   }

}
```

Comment: Sorry about it being unclear. Maybe thats why someone downvoted. What I meant was when a value is validated in the callback function which is in my model it is also processed, in this case the format of the submitted date is changed. I wanted to return this new value so that I can then use it in my controller. thanks for your help

Comment: In my example above, when your model returns the value to the `callback` in the controller, you can assign this processed value to a private variable. The value will then be accessible as you need. See edit.

Comment: @fl3x7: Did that solve your issue? Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: yep that works although what im thinking of doing is moving the callabck functions into the controller and just assign the new variable to $this->data['something']. Although I know this goes against the skinny controller fat model principal. Thanks for your help mate :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public function myTest($data){ // as the callback made by "callback_myTest"
     // Do your stuff here
    if(condition failed)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('myTest', "Your string message");
        return false;
    } 
    else 
    {
       return true;
    }
}
```

Please try this one.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at function _execute in file Form_validation of codeigniter. It sets var $_field_data to the result of callback gets(If the result is not boolean). There is another function "set_value". Use it with the parameter which is name of your field e.g. set_value('testPost') and see if you can get the result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So im returning the new string and then echoing set_value('testPost') but the value is still the original pre-processed value.

Answer (score 0):

The way Tank_Auth does this in a controller is like so

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('login', 'Login', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

if ($this->form_validation->run()) {        
// validation ok

$this->form_validation->set_value('login')

}
```

Using the set_value method of form_validation is undocumented however I believe this is how they get the processed value of login after it has been trimmed and cleaned.

I don't really like the idea of having to setup a new variable to store this value directly from the custom validation function.

Answer (score 0):

edit: sorry, misunderstood the question.  Use a custom callback, perhaps. Or use the php $_POST collection (skipping codeigniter)...apologies haven't tested, but I hope someone can build on this...

eg:

```
function _is_startdate_first($str)
{
           $str= do something to $str;

            or 

            $_POST['myinput'} = do something to $str;

    }
```

================

This is how I rename my custom callbacks:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('_is_startdate_first', 'The start date must be first');
```

.....

Separately, here's the callback function:

```
function _is_startdate_first($str)
{
    $startdate = new DateTime($this->input->post('startdate'), new DateTimeZone($this->tank_auth->timezone()));
    $enddate = new DateTime($this->input->post('enddate'), new DateTimeZone($this->tank_auth->timezone()));

    if ($startdate>$enddate) {
        return false;
        } else {
        return true;
        }
}
```